# How do I reconnect cake pieces that stuck to pan?

Tags: cake

I baked a commercial funfetti cake. When I removed it from the pan, a piece of the bottom of the cake stuck to the pan. I was able to remove those pieces with a spatula and place them on the cake.

How do I secure them to cake body? Can I just put a little frosting between the pieces or is there another way that works well?

Comment: Use icing, but thin it some, so it's not going to go on too thick.  You don't want it too runny, but you want it to flow a bit on its own ... think of a self leveling compound.  (because if you have to spread it in the crack, you risk tearing up the cake in the process, making the whole thing worse)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience using frosting to join broken cake will just draw attention to the fact something went wrong. If the loose part is on the bottom you can rely on gravity to keep it together, and when you slice it up if it comes apart you just put it on the plate and say nothing.

If gravity is not going to do the job then frosting will work fine, but be a bit obvious. Less obtrusive is food glue, which is simply watered down white fondant icing/sugar paste.